# How to convert image.RGBA (image.Image) to image.Paletted?

Tags: go, gif, animated-gif

I'm trying to create an animated GIF from a series of arbitrary non-paletted images. In order to create a paletted image, I need to come up with a palette somehow.

```
// RGBA, etc. images from somewhere else
var frames []image.Image

outGif := &gif.GIF{}
for _, simage := range frames {
  // TODO: Convert image to paletted image
  // bounds := simage.Bounds()
  // palettedImage := image.NewPaletted(bounds, ...)

  // Add new frame to animated GIF
  outGif.Image = append(outGif.Image, palettedImage)
  outGif.Delay = append(outGif.Delay, 0)
}
gif.EncodeAll(w, outGif)
```

Is there an easy way in golang stdlib to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of generating your own palette, you can also use on of the predefined (https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/palette/)

```
...
palettedImage := image.NewPaletted(bounds, palette.Plan9)
draw.Draw(palettedImage, palettedImage.Rect, simage, bounds.Min, draw.Over)
...
```

Comment: Is it just for me or this draw.Draw function takes a **lot** of time to execute! Is there any workaround for this? For a GIF, I tried using multiple goroutines to encode my GIF but this draw function is a bottleneck!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma  I also experienced the same on a Mac Pro

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I had the same issue. Turns out the color palette can have a huge effect on performance in Draw. Using gogif.MedianCutQuantizer from Taylor Hughes' answer for a color palette below gave me a big speedup.

Comment: `darw.Draw` is very slow. The dither process is extremely slow. While it takes microseconds to write PNG image sequences to disk, gif frames take 5-6 seconds.

Answer (score 8):

It seems an automatic way of intelligently generating palettes is missing from the golang stdlib (correct me if I'm wrong here). But there seems to be a stub for providing your own `Quantizer`, which led me to the `gogif` project. (Which was the apparent source of `image.Gif`.)

I was able to borrow the `MedianCutQuantizer` from that project, defined here:

https://github.com/andybons/gogif/blob/master/mediancut.go

Which results in the following:

```
var subimages []image.Image // RGBA, etc. images from somewhere else

outGif := &gif.GIF{}
for _, simage := range subimages {
  bounds := simage.Bounds()
  palettedImage := image.NewPaletted(bounds, nil)
  quantizer := gogif.MedianCutQuantizer{NumColor: 64}
  quantizer.Quantize(palettedImage, bounds, simage, image.ZP)

  // Add new frame to animated GIF
  outGif.Image = append(outGif.Image, palettedImage)
  outGif.Delay = append(outGif.Delay, 0)
}
gif.EncodeAll(w, outGif)
```

Comment: You can move the quantizer out of the loop, it contains no state other than NumColor so you don't need to create a new one every iteration.

Comment: This was created after your question, but Eric Pauley's [go-quantize](https://github.com/ericpauley/go-quantize/) is a nice tool for this purpose.

Comment: `quantizer.Quantize(palettedImage, bounds, simage, image.ZP)`  

This line is very slow for writing gif frames.